# If FIELD-A has PIC 9V99

Tags: cobol

If FIELD-A has PIC 9V99, to print the decimal point I would move FIELD-A to an edited field with what type of PIC clause? I am a beginner and not sure where to start.

Comment: You need to be able to answer questions like this yourself. You know it needs to be edited, you have a specification of some type, which shows you what the output needs to look like, so consulting your documentation (or any COBOL documentation) will give you your answer quicker than posting a question here. And don't even consider calling things FIELD-A. Use meaningful names.

Comment: I didn't realize asking questions here that are easy for others was a bad thing.

Comment: What is a bad thing is asking a question which can have 20 answers, none of which may be what you are looking for. It is simple to read documentation, understand it at a particular level, try it out, and review your reading/understanding of the documentation. If still stuck after that, you post your question with all the detail, so that an answer to your question (not just some random answer from many possible) can be provided, with explanation to clear your misunderstanding that you have with a particular part of the language. If that is too tiring,  don't expect much in return.

Comment: I was still stuck after reading documentation. I didn't understand the documentation at the time. The question posted was the exact question that was given to me without any extra explanation. I was confused, hence, asking a question to this forum.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, 9.99 or perhaps 99.99 (if you wanted a leading zero).  You could also use something like Z9.99 to suppress leading zeroes.  Or $Z.99 for to put a currency sign, that sort of thing.

Comment: All your suggestions could be correct, as could... 20 more? Makes the question too broad. You could be correct (except for the "suppress leading zero" example, they are all plausible suggestions) but can't bring myself to upvote :-) Since you are close, I'll see if I can find another of your answers which looks good...

Comment: Actually, they are all quite feasible.  He asked the question, I answered.  I didn't ask the question so if it is too broad that's on the OP.  I was just trying to give the guy an answer that would work for him.  As to upvoting, it isn't something of interest to me so no big deal there.

Comment: You can't use the Z9.99 to zero-suppress a 9V99 field, can you? I thought you may want to get a bit closer to 2000. Yes, it is not your fault the question is too broad, but you chose to answer it.